# CarrierWave::Crop::ProcessingError (Failed to crop - :en is not a valid locale)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, carrierwave

I'm working on a rails project on which I have a product model with a field to upload a picture. I'm using the carrierwave gem for the uploads and the project is in a server running nginx.

I need to upload the pictures on the path `public/uploads` inside the project. On the development environment everything works fine, but on production the site crash when I upload a picture.

I already checked the production log on thee server with the command `tails /var/log/nginx/error.log`, but for some reason it just shows me as far as before the POST/PATCH actions.

This is my `product` model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

end
```

This is my `picture uploader` file:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process crop: [400, 400]

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    'uploads'
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpeg jpg png)
  end

  def content_type_whitelist
    /image\//
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) || model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end

end
```

And this is the nginx configuration that I have for the site:

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/project/current/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby;
}
```

**Thanks so much in advance :)**

**EDIT**

I was looking the wrong log. the production log was at `/var/www/project/current/log`

This is the error that I get:

```
D, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.330282 #1341] DEBUG -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331113 #1341] DEBUG -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e]    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
I, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331277 #1341]  INFO -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
F, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331669 #1341] FATAL -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e]   
F, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331691 #1341] FATAL -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e] CarrierWave::Crop::ProcessingError (Failed to crop - :en is not a valid locale):
F, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331704 #1341] FATAL -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e]   
F, [2017-07-04T16:50:19.331716 #1341] FATAL -- : [c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e] app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39:in `block in update'
[c7b9956c-786f-440c-bc38-e13718f3493e] app/controllers/products_controller.rb:38:in `update'
```

Apparently, it is a problem with the locale files. I'm also using the [carrierwave-crop-on-fly](https://github.com/evg2108/carrierwave-crop-on-fly) gem to crop the image when it's uploaded, which seems to be part of the error.

I have this on my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
config.i18n.available_locales = :es
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
```

I'll update the question if I find the answer

Comment: At the end I included the en file in locale variables and got the error `translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error`. Turns out I didn't had imagemagick on the server. I solved it by running `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` on the remote server. I'll leave the question in case someone else been as clueless as me :P

Comment: You can add the text from this comment as an answer to your own question, that is allowed and you will help other that have a similar issue in the future. Another point is to update your title with the error message you get ex:  "CarrierWave::Crop::ProcessingError (Failed to crop - :en is not a valid locale)", that will help people more.

Answer (score 0):

After the en.yml file was added and included in the locale, the next error was: `translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error`.

Turns out Imagemagick wasn't installed on the server.

To solve it you need to run: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` on the remote server.

**Credit goes to [kenneth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8255882/kenneth) for answering the question himself.**